# WPF ComboBox does not display content

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a simple combo box on my xaml file:

```
    <ComboBox Name="environmentComboBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" 
              SelectionChanged="environmentComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
```

Here is the code for its content:

```
    private List<string> test = new List<string>(){"1", "2"};

    public List<string> Test
    {
        get
        {
            return test;
        }
        set
        {
            test = value;
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug the application, the ComboBox does not show anything.
But when I checked if Test has content, it shows the two strings.

Comment: Have to set the views `DataContext` to the `Model/Window` containing the `List<string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have to set the views `DataContext` to the `Model/Window` containing the `List<T>`?

If not you need to tell the View what `DataContext` to use, below is a quick example of a WPF window, and setting the xamls `DataContext` to the code behind of the View.

Also its recommended to use `ObservableCollection<T>` when binding collections as adding and removing items will update the `ComboBox` automatically

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; // set datacontext
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> test = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2" };
    public ObservableCollection<string> Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, that seemed to fix the problem I was having.
Thank you for helping me and I apologize for the trivial question.

Comment: No problems, and remember this is what Stack overflow is for, no question is trivial if you are stuck :)